# How do I put a container over a generated list in the body of a page?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to put a container over a generated list in the body of a page however the container and the list don't show up when I embed them in a ListView.

Here is my code:

```
final dummySnapshot = [
  {"courseTitle": "Course title - Course 0", "completeness": "incomplete"},
  {"courseTitle": "Course title - Course 1", "completeness": "incomplete"},
  {"courseTitle": "Course title - Course 2", "completeness": "incomplete"},
];

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key key, this.user}) : super(key: key);
  final FirebaseUser user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Example Text A"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          mainHeader(),
          MyList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget mainHeader() {
  return Container(
    height: 50.0,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "Example Text B",
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyListState createState() {
    return MyListState();
  }
}

class MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBody(context);
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildList(context, dummySnapshot);
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<Map> snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, Map data) {
    final record = Record.fromMap(data);

    return Padding(
      key: ValueKey(record.courseTitle),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(record.courseTitle),
          trailing: Text(record.completeness),
          onTap: () => print(record),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Record {
  final String courseTitle;
  final String completeness;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['courseTitle'] != null),
        assert(map['completeness'] != null),
        courseTitle = map['courseTitle'],
        completeness = map['completeness'];

  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$courseTitle:$completeness>";
}
```

When this code is run in my Xcode simulator the entire body doesn't show, only the app bar. However when I get rid of the body's ListView and run the mainHeader() only in the body the container shows up and when I run the MyList() only in the body the list also shows up. Is there a way to get both to show?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your body like -

```
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          mainHeader(),   // Container
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true, // add this
              children: <Widget>[
                MyList(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

In your Second `Listview` add `shrinkWrap: true,`:

```
Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<Map> snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,  // add this
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), // add this
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
    );
  }
```

You can also place `mainHeader()` in `ListView` and remove column. That will work also.

**UPDATE:**

```
body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          mainHeader(),
          MyList(),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: A column is not scrollable, your answer results in the list not being scrollable.

Comment: So remove column and add main header in list view. I mentioned it in answer.

Comment: Your answer still results in an unscrollable list.

Comment: `ListView` is scroll-able widget. what do you mean by - 'results in an unscrollable list' if you refer to second `ListView` - it could be because it is present in another `Listview`. Then you can try to add - `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),` in second `ListView` code. it should work.  @hello_friend